# Get an odom from scan

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I look for a package that can compute an odometry based on laser (for a robot without odometry, of course)
I have tested the odometry generated with hectorslam and it missed the Twist parameter within the odometry.
Did I miss something ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217611/get-an-odom-from-scan/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher). If all you want is odometry, hector slam is probably overkill.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2015-09-14**:
Is the calculation of odometry from laser scan data what people typically call "visual odometry"?  I always thought they were talking about calculating odometry from a video camera feed.  But this makes way way more sense.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-09-14**:
[Visual odometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry) does indeed refer to using camera data to calculate egomotion. I don't know if there's a good general term for using laser data for the same purpose.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-15**:
Visual odometry is the new fashion :-) .No seriously, I prefer using a good laser for the moment.
Laser_scan_matcher seems to do the job I need if I dont use hectorslam for the same purpose.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-15**:
By the way, I will make a new thread about how I struggle to set up hectorslam and navstack on my robot (the one without odom)

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-09-15**:
Good luck. I've also had trouble getting hector slam working reliably on a robot with no odom.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-16**:
And you succeed ?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-09-16**:
Not really.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-21**:
My bad, it's seems that laser_scan_matcher dont provide an odometry, that's not what I'm looking for.
Sorry I was too enthousiast. Do you have another solution ?